# The easiest way to plot a family of parametric curves

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a family of parametric curves.

$\qquad x=t-e^t+2s \quad y=e^t$

where $t$ belongs to $(0,\,1)$ and $s \in \{0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1\}$.

Just the simplest code, please.

Comment: This is indeed simple in Mma, so you should offer your initial attempt and then request additional guidance.

Comment: Look at ParametricPlot

Answer (score 5):

One possible way

[image]

```
ClearAll[x, t, s];
Manipulate[
  curves = {x[t, #], y[t]} & /@ s;

  ParametricPlot[curves, {t, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, 
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Automatic}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],

  {{s, Range[0, 1, .2], "s"}, Range[0, 1, .2], ControlType -> TogglerBar},

  Initialization :> (
   x[t_, s_] := t - Exp[t] + 2 s;
   y[t_] := Exp[t]
   )
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You ought to post your own attempt, as others have said.

The simplest code is something like:

```
ParametricPlot[{t - E^t + 2 #, E^t}, {t, 0, 1}] & /@ Range[0, 1, .2]
```

You can look at the documentation (another excellent learning tool) to figure out how to make that less ugly. If you just want basic labels, *e.g.*:

```
ParametricPlot[{t - E^t + 2 #, E^t}, {t, 0, 1},PlotLabel->"s = "<>ToString@#] & /@ Range[0, 1, .2]
```

Comment: tweaking your example, you can get them into one plot with `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{t - E^t + 2 #, E^t} & /@ Range[0, 1, .2]], {t, 0, 1}]`